# Springboot spring data JPA using join and pagination

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Java: 20.0

Springboot: 3.0.1

Table structure

```
posts | CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `posts` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK8omq0tc18jd43bu5tjh6jvra7taq` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8omq0tc18jd43bu5tjh6jvra7taq` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

Post entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "posts")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Post {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @UuidGenerator(style = UuidGenerator.Style.TIME)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(length = 5000)
  private String comment;

  @ManyToOne
  @JsonBackReference
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  @ToStringExclude
  private User user;

  @Column(name = "deleted_by")
  private String deletedBy;

  @Column(name = "created_at")
  private Timestamp createdAt;

  @Column(name = "updated_at")
  private Timestamp updatedAt;


  @JsonManagedReference
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
  @ToStringExclude
  private List<PostReport> postReports = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

post_reports

```
post_reports | CREATE TABLE `post_reports` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `reported_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reported_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reported_reason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKj9so403o1bquehozscdqxpyijjma` (`post_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKj9so403o1bquehozscdqxpyijjma` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

PostReport entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "post_reports")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class PostReport {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @UuidGenerator(style = UuidGenerator.Style.TIME)
  private UUID id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
  @JsonBackReference
  @ToStringExclude
  private Post post;

  @Column(name = "reported_by")
  private String reportedBy;

  @Column(name = "reported_reason")
  private String reportedReason;

  @Column(name = "reported_at")
  private Timestamp reportedAt;

  @Column(name = "updated_by")
  private String updatedBy;

  @Column(name = "updated_at")
  private Timestamp updatedAt;
}
```

Application Properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerMySQLDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc-secretsmanager:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:some.rds.amazonaws.com}:3306/dbname
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.sql.init.mode=always 
hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
```

Query

```
@Query(
      value =
          "SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN post_reports AS pr ON p.id=pr.post_id WHERE (pr.reported_by IS NULL OR pr.reported_by!=:reportedBy) order by p.created_at",
      countQuery =
          "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.*) FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN FETCH post_reports AS pr ON p.id= pr.post_id WHERE (pr.reported_by IS NULL OR pr.reported_by!=:reportedBy)",
      nativeQuery = true)
  Page<Post> findAllByReportedByNullOrReportedByNot(
      @Param("reportedBy") String reportedBy, Pageable pageable);
```

*This gives unknown field `p.createdAt.*` error. Because in table the name is `created_at` it is not recognising the column.

**Solution**

I am passing `String sortBy = "createdAt";` which is the reason for this issue. but my other JPA queries are taking this as attribute name is createdAt, so I created another pageable object by String sortBy2 = "created_at"; for this query and if I am using this, it is working. Would like to make it work with createdAt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above post needs two modification to make it work properly

1. Create a new pageable object with `created_at` and pass that in the native query, because native query understands table column and not the attribute of the entity class.
2. The query will again include filtered data when the post gets reported by another user.

so, correct implementation will be

```
String sortBy = "created_at";
Sort sort = Sort.by(sortBy).descending();
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, limit, sort);
postRepository. findAllByReportedByNullOrReportedByNot(@Param("reportedBy") String reportedBy, Pageable pageable)
```

Definition of the query will look like:

```
@Query(
      value =
          "SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM posts p WHERE p.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT pr.post_id FROM post_reports pr WHERE pr.reported_by = : reportedBy)",
      nativeQuery = true)
  Page<Post> findAllByReportedByNullOrReportedByNot(
      @Param("reportedBy") String reportedBy, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: This is correct, as native query won't understand the JPA column we have define in entity, Specially for sort either we can explicitly convert the property from camelCase to SnakeCase in the controller before passing to Service.

Comment: @Afsar yes, either we need to use native column names or need to make sure native column names and attributes names are same.

Comment: In our projects, we have a common pagination method, which will take care of request param for sort, size and convert sort column to snake case from camel case or add default values.

Answer (score 1):

Please share your entity class as well for better answer.

You need to set up either of the below

1. Setup a Naming Strategy
2. Use lowercase column names in your annotations

as a property shown in below example or by creating custom strategy.

```
 spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, will try it and also update the question with entity class.

Comment: This is not working, will add entity class now.

Comment: without seeing your application.yml/properties file and @Entity class, it's hard to provide any suggestion, please update those 2

Comment: Added entity classes and application properties can you please have a look?

Comment: I solved the issue by making pageable object with `created_at`. but would like to make it work with createdAt.

Comment: I have added a proper answer to this below, if you can have a look, the query is also an interesting part of the change required. I was quite busy, so there is delay in posting it.